# Making a clickable JXTable or JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jxtable

I have created a web crawler and then a GUI for users to search through the database etc… What I would like is now for the JXTable to clickable to go to the URL. Here is my code for the JXTable:

```
outPut = new JXTable(tableModel);
add(new JScrollPane(outPut), BorderLayout.CENTER);
outPut.setEditable(false);
AbstractHyperlinkAction<Object> simpleAction = new AbstractHyperlinkAction<Object>(null) {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //No idea what goes here
    }
};
```

I have got it to display from the database as shown below but have no clue how to make the cells clickable.

[image]

Just shows the output of the search result

This is supposed to be the mouse listener for the table. Doesn't work at all sadly. I have set the table edit to false as well. I'm not sure where to go after this cause I'm not sure if the research I'm reading is correct or not.

```
private static boolean isURLColumn(JTable outPut, int column) {
    return column>=0 && outPut.getColumnClass(column).equals(URL.class);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    outPut = (JTable)e.getSource();
    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    int ccol = outPut.columnAtPoint(pt);
    if(isURLColumn(outPut, ccol)) {
        int crow = outPut.rowAtPoint(pt);
        URL url = (URL)outPut.getValueAt(crow, ccol);
        try {
            if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that populates the JTable using a default table model:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rS.getMetaData();
// Names of columns
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
    columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
}

// Data of the table
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<>();
while (rS.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        vector.add(rS.getObject(i));
    }
    data.add(vector);
}

tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);
tableModel.setRowCount(maxRow);
```

Comment: That is not a `SSCCE`. I can't compile the code since it is not complete. I don't have access to your database. Create a simple JFrame with a simple JTable. Hardcode the URL into one or two cells of the table. Add the MouseListener to the table and click, on the cell containing the URL. The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the problem to its basics.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom editor. Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Other Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor). The example displays a JColorChooser dialog when you double click on the cell. You could customize the code to display your URL is a webpage.

Take a look at the table of contents. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Integrate With the Desktop Class` which makes it easy to display your system browser.

Or the other option is to add a MouseListener to the table and then display the browser, again using the desktop class. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Write a MouseListener`.

Comment: To be honest I have no clue what im doing now as I have never used any of this stuff before. Does below look remotely right in a mouse listener?

Comment: outPut = (JXTable)e.getSource();
    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    int ccol = outPut.columnAtPoint(pt);
    if(isURLColumn(outPut, ccol)) {
      int crow = outPut.rowAtPoint(pt);
      URL url = (URL)outPut.getValueAt(crow, ccol);
     
      try{
        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) { 
          Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
        }

Comment: @Relentless Don't post code is a comment. As you can see it is not formatted and difficult to read. Code looks reasonable. If it doesn't work then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem in your question. And use a JTable in the `SSCCE` so we don't have to download JXTable just to test your code.